# Inputing drop list"option value" into javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a document title timer function which reflect the selected login time the user choose using a drop down list.

So far i have gotten the timer working with a default time of 30 seconds and i am having problem linking the drop down "option value" to my javascript.

What i dont understand is that wont my variable $droptime dynamically grab the value from the drop down "option value" ?

**index.php**

```
<form id="form1" align="left" method="POST" action="second.php">
<select name ="droptime">
 <option id="5" value="5" >5 Seconds</option>
 <option id="10" value="10">10 Seconds</option>
 <option id="15" value="15">15 Seconds</option>
 <option id="30" value="30">30 Seconds</option>
</select>   
</form>
```

This is my javascript for the document title

**second.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$drop_time = $_SESSION['droptimeD'];
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src= "index.php">
    <!-- //

    var m = <?php echo $drop_time; ?> ;
    var i = new Number(m);
    function titleTimer(){
    document.title = "Time till logout - " + i + " seconds.";
    i -= 1;
    if(i < 0){
    document.title = "Please login Again"
    window.location.replace("index.php");
    }else{
    setTimeout("titleTimer()", 1000);
    }
    }
    // -->
    </script>
```

I apologies if there might be a duplicate question. I did search through the forum and tried multiple solution to no available and i suspect i am missing a crucial part to get it to work.

Comment: You are mixing PHP context with Javascript context. Javascript is executed on browser whereas PHP is executed on back-end and it's result is returned on HTTP response.

Comment: you may want to try <?=$droptime?>  or  <?=$_POST['droptime']?> in your JS

Comment: Solved the problem. There is 2 issue with my coding. Firstly the form area which is directed else where. Secondly i didnt call the variable the proper way thus was unable to pharse the value over. Edited the question with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its abit weird but i was parsing data all over the place plus the confusion. Also i mixed up php and java script context

index.php

```
<form id="form1" align="left" method="POST" action="second.php">
<select name ="droptime">
 <option id="5" value="5" >5 Seconds</option>
 <option id="10" value="10">10 Seconds</option>
 <option id="15" value="15">15 Seconds</option>
 <option id="30" value="30">30 Seconds</option>
</select>   
</form>
```

This is my javascript for the document title

second.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$drop_time = $_SESSION['droptimeD'];
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src= "index.php">
    <!-- //

    var m = <?php echo $drop_time; ?> ;
    var i = new Number(m);
    function titleTimer(){
    document.title = "Time till logout - " + i + " seconds.";
    i -= 1;
    if(i < 0){
    document.title = "Please login Again"
    window.location.replace("index.php");
    }else{
    setTimeout("titleTimer()", 1000);
    }
    }
    // -->
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As mesutozer said, you can't use the php variable in javascript. You have to grab the value from the html document using something like

```
var i = document.getElementsByName('droptime')[0].value;
```

Comment: I prefer using getElementById but in this case, what is you particular Problem with it? [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

Comment: Sorry! my head is not in it's place :)

Comment: Thanks very much @Bowdzone . Just to check with you what happens if both my form and javascript are on different php page ? Do i have to add something else to call the element name ?

Comment: do you load that javascript in your php page?

Comment: Yes i did. They are just in separate php files. The form is in the index.php while the javascript is in second.php

Comment: If you have some sort of <script src="..."> tag in you index.php head section that javascript is loaded into the document.

Comment: @Bowdzone i did what you have suggest and have edited my code in the question. The changes broke the javascript code. I might just try to work this issue out slowly. THank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Solved the problem. There is 2 issue with my coding. Firstly the form area which is directed else where. Secondly i didnt call the variable the proper way thus was unable to pharse the value over.

Edited the question with solution